# Flex app cannot download images from other servers

Tags: apache-flex, crossdomain.xml

in my flex application:

```
<mx:Image  id="imgItem" source="http://notMySyte.com/1.jpg"/>
```

when i run my app, I catch this error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://mySite.com/2/BusFlex/BusProducts.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/2 cannot access http://cs9621.notMySite.com/u7397474/c_b51d9fe6.jpg. A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
at flash.display::Loader/get content()
at mx.controls::SWFLoader/get content()
at mx.controls::SWFLoader/doSmoothBitmapContent()
at mx.controls::SWFLoader/updateDisplayList()
at mx.controls::Image/updateDisplayList()
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateDisplayList()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()
```

help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly allow cross-domain access by creating a crossdomain.xml file in your root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    </cross-domain-policy>
    ...
```

Comment: I have this file. But nothing(

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear.  When @colithium says "your root folder" he means the root folder of the domain serving the images, not the root folder of the domain serving the SWF.

Comment: radical.ru - this is hosting of my images. http://www.radikal.ru/crossdomain.xml - crossdomain file of this hosting. He is valid. http://chfmm.ru/2 - my site. Click on the sit, and you see the preview of sits. Click at the some sit, and you see this error.

Comment: @GLeBaTi - Why is this answer marked as correct when you're commenting that it's still broken here, can you confirm you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The *site you are loading images from* has to explicitly grant Flash/Flex applications by hosting a cross-domain.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a crossdomain.xml file. After that you need to explicitly load that crossdomain file using the code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://foo.com/crossdomain.xml");
```